# How can I react to a file change outside of my python docker container?

Tags: python, windows, docker, filesystems

This is my very first question, please bear with me :)

Now:
I have a quite complex python application in a docker container.

System info:

```
Windows Server 2016  
Docker 18.03  
Base: python:3.7-alpine
```

I need to **react to some file content changes on my host system and its network shares**.
The python scripts need only to be invoked when a change happens (about 500 / day).

So I wonder what would be more practical, secure and scalable in the future:

> watch these files under my host system and then run my container if
>   needed with a loaded copy of the changed file

or

> share the relevant folders with my container, implement the file
>   monitoring in my application and have it run on idle

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "scalable" here -- if you want multiples of your python script to react to the same file, or do you mean scaling in terms of the number of files worked on -- so you'd still have one python worker per file, but multiple files?

I'd prefer the second option to the first, certainly while debugging, because the container instances will be easier to interact with. I'd also assume that an idling container takes up less system resources than re-starting a container frequently. But taking measurements of system performance in both cases is the right thing to do here.

Comment: @SaraSinback The scalability in this case is only about the number of machines/users (maybe a couple of hundred compared to just 5 now)
So on a per machine base the amount of files stays the same. Every system writes to its own set of files on the network share, so yes I will need one python worker per file.
Scaling an amout of docker containers is quite easy, thats why I considered the first option, although the second would be the best choice for a smaller number of client machines.
Thanks for the input, I guess taking measurements of the produced load will be essential here.